# Are old Installers compatible with Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

i have a bunch of visual novels that install start menu shortcuts, here's a snippit of what i have installed

```
Programs/Visual Novels/BROCCOLI/Galaxy Angel/Moon Angel-tai/Galaxy Angel
Programs/Visual Novels/BROCCOLI/Galaxy Angel/Moon Angel-tai/Galaxy Angel - Eternal Lovers
Programs/Visual Novels/Eushully/Meister/Kamidori Alchemy Meister
Programs/Visual Novels/Liar-Soft/-What a Beautiful-/Sekien no Inganock -What a Beautiful People-
Programs/Visual Novels/Liar-Soft/-What a Beautiful-/Shikkoku no Sharnoth -What a Beautiful Tomorrow-
Programs/Visual Novels/Liar-Soft/Forest
Programs/Visual Novels/TYPE-MOON/Fate/Fate Stay Night
Programs/Visual Novels/TYPE-MOON/Fate/Fate Hollow Ataraxia
Programs/Visual Novels/TYPE-MOON/Tsukihime/Tsukihime/Tsukihime - Blue Blue Glass Moon
Programs/Visual Novels/TYPE-MOON/Tsukihime/Tsukihime/Kagetsu Tohya
Programs/Visual Novels/TYPE-MOON/Tsukihime/Melty Blood/Melty Blood - Hologram Summer
Programs/Visual Novels/TYPE-MOON/Tsukihime/Melty Blood/Melty Blood - ReAct
```

from what i saw of Windows 8 from a work mate's laptop, the start menu is gone and what they have this this other menu which everything seems to be in categories rather than a folder network like what i'm using

now if it was just .exe for the Visual Novels it wouldn't be much of a problem however Mirror Moon released wlakthough flow charts for Fate/Stay Night, Tsukihime and Kagetsu Tohya which have a shortcut in the start menu, Galaxy Angel has multiple .exes which have shortcuts and Kamidori Alchemy Meister has a separate Config application

i want to know if Windows 8 will still run installers that allow you to specify a start menu shortcut as i dont want to upgrade and find out that i can't install anything

i also make installers for my programs that do the same thing so it is important i know this incase if i now have to take into account compatibility with Windows 8

Comment: The Win8 [All Apps](http://www.askvg.com/create-direct-shortcut-to-all-apps-page-of-windows-8-start-screen-and-pin-it-to-taskbar/) screen *should* display the shortcuts. If in doubt I guess you can always try the OS in a VM first to check compatibility with your old programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The start screen works almost identically to the old start menu as far as older software is concerned - it draws from the same location old start menu used to, or you can add shortcuts yourself. Some *installers* may need to be run in compatibility mode, but this is uncommon, and has nothing to do with the startscreen

Answer (score 1):

You will not have any problem . While installing you can right click on software which you want to install and then wait till computer computes the possible options then click on the option worked on windows xp. click on OK.

You can find your application irrespective of .exe or not just by clicking on windows button and typing its name. It will come up with search results which will contain your application